# git merge after file renamed

Tags: git, version-control, merge, conflict, mv

I have two files `A` and `B` in master. I created a branch `feature` where I modified both `A` and `B`. Then, someone else deleted `B` and renamed `A` to `B` in `master` (using git mv).

When I merge `feature` into `master`, git compares `B` in `feature` with `B` in `master`, which is not as what I expected, because the content of `B` is actually the content of `A` in master.

Is there any built-in feature that can link `A` in `feature` with `B` in `master` when I merge it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename the file to match in either side or change the threshold percentage until git sees them as the same file. I believe it's the `-M` option.

Answer (score 0):

What is going to happen to `B` in your `master` branch? If `A` is supposed to be called `B` then why not just rename it in your `feature` branch as well. Of course first rename `B` to something else like `C`, and it will merge normally.

Comment: I should have mentioned that when they renamed A to B, they also made some changes in the content. They are C++ files. When they renamed the file, they changed the corresponding class names, include guard, variable names..

Comment: If there are modifications in the files that conflict, then the only solution is to manually fix the conflicts, but often git can merge both of the modified contents provided it knows they are the same file. Having the same name will let it know to try to merge them together.